# How to get menu tree from a node to build a customize breadcrumb?

Tags: nodes, breadcrumbs

I would like to build a custom breadcrumb based on node relation from entity reference. For example there is a book node that has menu hierarchy:

```
Book
|-chapter 1
|--sub chapter 1.1
|---sub sub chapter 1.1.1
|----#Node with different content type and not included/displayed on Book
      Navigation
```

The Page Node (sub sub chapter 1.1.1) has entity reference relation with node biblio (for ex)

What I want is when I access biblio then the breadcrumb is displayed like the above tree.

Possible solution:
Write a code using nexus theme on template.php on function:

```
function nexus_breadcrumb($variables) {

  //$breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
  //$node = $variables['node'];

  if ($node->type == 'biblio'){
   // pseudo code start
   // get 'book' node that point to biblio
   // get menu tree from the book node
   // construct the menu tree and assign it to $breadcrumb

   // this is I still not know how to code the section.
  }

  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
  // Use CSS to hide titile .element-invisible.
  $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';
   // comment below line to hide current page to breadcrumb

  $output .= '<nav class="breadcrumb">' . implode(' » ', $breadcrumb) .   
   '</nav>';
   return $output;
  } 
}
```

Any help will do. Thank you.

Comment: I was going to suggest Crumbs for this, but now I'm not even sure it fully supports book module.. I think it does if you enable menu.hierarchy.* wildcard. The book menus will not show up as crumbs plugins, but it is ok if the menu.hierarchy.* wildcard is enabled. Then for the entityreference part you can enable one of the entityreference plugins. And don't be afraid of the UI. --- I will make this a real answer if someone can confirm that it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Menu Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb)

> - Append the page title to the breadcrumb (either as a clickable url or    not)
> - Hide the breadcrumb if it only contains the link to the front    page.
> - Generate the breadcrumb from the URL structure if content does    not belong to a menu (7.x-1.6 and older only)

For more details [click here](http://www.cmsquickstart.com/blog/tutorial-how-work-and-style-breadcrumbs-drupal-7)

[Custom Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs)

> Many new features have been added including support for Views, Panels,
>   Taxonomy vocabularies and terms, paths, and a simple API that allows
>   contributed modules to enable custom breadcrumbs for module pages and
>   theme templates. These are implemented using optional, independent
>   submodules that depend on the main Custom Breadcrumbs module.
>
> In addition to breadcrumb visibility, this version provides an option
>   permitting PHP code snippets to be used in forming the breadcrumb
>   titles and paths. Multiple languages are also supported.